# Angular ui-router different master page layout for different views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, angular-ui-router-extras

I am working on a ui-router issue.

I've managed to configure the main master page which will be in use throughout the child pages. Child pages content is fetched correctly as well.

Now, the point where I'm stuck is the login/register view. Since they'll not be part of the same master layout, they will be simple layout with html controls in the center of the page and nothing else I'm having a hard time to understand how can I include the login / register in the ui-router logic.

This is what I have so far:

ui-router logic:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider
      .state("home", {
          url: "/home",
          templateUrl: "/views/home/index.html",
          controller: "homeController",
          contrllerAs: "homeCtrl",
          data: {
              css: '/assets/css/homepage.css'
          }
      })
        .state("ourteam", {
            url: "/ourteam",
            templateUrl: "/views/home/our-team.html"
        })
    .state("accountlogin", {
        url: "/accountlogin",
        templateUrl: "/views/home/login.html",
        controller: "loginController"
    })
});
```

master page (not the one for login) markup in shortened version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/" />
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ui-router-styles class="fixed-footer home-page">
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class=" navbar">
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-nav-relm">
                        <li class="active"><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Borrowers <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a ui-sref="Link1">Link1</a></li>
                                <li><a ui-sref="Link2">Link2</a></li>
                                <li><a ui-sref="Link3">Link3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a ui-sref="ourteam">Our Team</a></li>
                        <li><a ui-sref="contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a ui-sref="accountlogin">Login</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- START CHILD CONTENT -->
 <ui-view></ui-view>
    <!-- END CHILD CONTENT -->
   </body>
</html>
```

Login page (shortened version):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body class="login">
    <div class="content" ng-app="app">
        <!-- BEGIN LOGIN FORM -->
        <div class="login-form" ng-controller="loginController">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input data-ng-model="loginData.userName" required autofocus/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input data-ng-model="loginData.password" required/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" ng-click="Login()">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END LOGIN FORM -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now what will be the proper way to redirect to that new layout (or incorporate in the existing master page)?

Comment: I think no choice but you have to restructure your HTML DOM nodes and also your state hierarchy. The navbar should be inside the `ui-view`

Answer (score -1):

in 'Login function', first try authenticating the user by using backend methods and services like [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) and JWT.and then redirect to particular state if there's no error.
Try this tutorial [Authenticate a Node.js API with JSON Web Tokens](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens)

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand the question. I just want to display the proper layout with ui-router

Comment: that is not what he is asking for